# How to create a table field with Multipolygon datatype in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How can I create a table field with multipolygon datatype in NodeJs sequelize?

```
myfield: {
    type: ?????,
    allowNull: true
}
```

The MySQL table structure is -

```
CREATE TABLE `contextoccurrence` (
  `field1` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `myfield` polygon DEFAULT NULL,

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm now learning about Sequelize and trying to insert geometry fields (type: DataTypes.GEOMETRY).

Following Sequelize docs (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/variable/index.html), it seems it's not possible to insert a multipolygon if using MySQL, and not sure in case of PostgreSQL:

> A column storing Geometry information. It is only available in PostgreSQL (with PostGIS) or MySQL. In MySQL, allowable Geometry types are POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON.
>   GeoJSON is accepted as input and returned as output.